# Injecting Dependencies into un-Parceled Objects - Best Practices?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, parcelable, dagger-2

I have a domain entity - let's assume it's a `Car` - which contains a repository implementation that I inject via Dagger. When I'm testing my entity, I swap out the repository for a mock implementation. `Car` also `implements Parcelable`.

Dagger can construct the object when `Car(Engine)` is invoked but it obviously fails to do when the `Car(Parcel)` is invoked since it is called internally by the Parcelization Framework (usually when getting `Car` from an `Intent`).

Is it a good idea to inject dependencies manually in the `Car(Parcel)` constructor? Alternatively, is there a best practice that you could recommend? Injecting dependencies in the `Parcel` constructor would definitely solve my issues, but it's recommended practice that dependencies not be injected in constructors so as to maintain Separation of Concerns between instantiation and injection logic.

Here's my domain entity

```
public class Car implements Parcelable {

    @Inject ICarRepository CarRepositoryImpl;

    private Engine engine; // User specified engine passed through constructor

    public Car(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public Car(Parcel parcel) {
        this.engine = getEngine(parcel); // Read engine from parcel
        // Inject dependencies here? 
    }

    // Static Parcelable creator and other methods follow...
}
```

Comment: I don't think that anyone is able to answer this. I do not know why you need a `CarRepositoryImpl` in a model class (it looks like it should be a plain model?) or why you don't use constructor injection, but inject the object somehow some place else. Also if every field is also parcelable, you could just parcel the object and recreate it as a whole. (Again, I think parcelable is / should just be used by model classes, hence...why that dependency?)

Comment: This isn't a model. It's a domain level entity which represents business logic in my application. I require the repository so act as an interface between the persistence layer and the domain (business logic) layer.

Answer (score 3):

David's comment on your question is spot on - why would `Car` have a dependency on `CarRepository`? This is most certainly an anti-pattern - Repositories are used to decouple entities from modelling/persistence; here you are introducing one for seemingly no reason whatsoever. However, let us assume for a minute that you've simply put the repository in there for sake of example.

Of course, Dagger has no automatic way of readying an Object once it is unparceled. This means, we'll have to invoke Dagger someplace.

The appropriate candidate, to the best of my judgement, would be your `public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR`, like so:

```
// Creator
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Car> CREATOR 
    = new Parcelable.Creator<>() {
        public Car createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            Car ret = new Car(in);
            DaggerCarComponent.builder().build().inject(ret);
            return ret;
        }
};
```

**Goals Achieved with this Technique**

- Your Dagger-specific code is not entangled with your instantiation logic within your constructor, but as a specific implementation of un-parcelling.
- Your Dagger-specific code is static and can be tested in isolation without having to instantiate `Car` through a `Parcel`.
- By using a `@Component`, not only is your code resistant to future changes (such as adding or removing dependencies), but also minimalist/DRY